# How to solve discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandRegistrationError?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I'm trying to code a bot for Discord and can't get my "help" command to work.

This is the code I started with:

```
@client.command(pass_context=True,name="help")
async def help(ctx):
    embed=discord.Embed(
        title="️ Commands",
        description="This is a test",
        color=0xc41a49
    )
    embed.add_field(
        name="Basic commands",
        value="This is a test"
    )
    await ctx.send(embed)
```

But whenever I run it, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Speed\PycharmProjects\InyeopBOT\inyeop.py", line 54, in <module>
    async def help(ctx):
  File "C:\Users\Speed\PycharmProjects\InyeopBOT\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 1263, in decorator
    self.add_command(result)
  File "C:\Users\Speed\PycharmProjects\InyeopBOT\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 1149, in add_command
    raise CommandRegistrationError(command.name)
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandRegistrationError: The command help is already an existing command or alias.
```

Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: decorator should be in the same level of def

Comment: I think you should pay more attention to what the first error message is telling you: "*The command help is already an existing command or alias*". You've tried to create a `help` command, but one already exists. Try using a different command name.

Comment: In your own words, where the error message says "The command help is already an existing command or alias.", exactly what do you suppose this means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create your help command using a `@client.command` you should define the default help command to None.

On the same line you've defined your client you should add the `help_command` argument set to `None`.
Should look like this:

```py
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='?', help_command=None, intents=discord.Intents.default())
```

Then align your `async def help` method with your `@client.command` decorator.

I also recommend you to check this [gist article](https://gist.github.com/InterStella0/b78488fb28cadf279dfd3164b9f0cf96) about help command. In fact discord.py have already a powerful system regarding help commands.

Answer (score -1):

The space you add to try fixing your first error is the reason for your second error.

In fact, reading the traceback is a good way to fix errors, if you look closely, the reason for your first error is : `The command help is already an existing command or alias`

Then you should rename your function, for instance :

```py
@client.command(pass_context=True,name="help")
async def custom_help(ctx):
    embed=discord.Embed(
        title="️ Commands",
        description="This is a test",
        color=0xc41a49
    )
    embed.add_field(
        name="Basic commands",
        value="This is a test"
    )
    await ctx.send(embed)
```